# Number precision in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm doing a website with angular, and I'm trying to sum two numbers and show them in a `< div >`, but I don't know how to manage the precision.

For example, with the following code:

**htlm:**

```
<div>{{sum}}</div>
```

**typescript:**

```
sum = 9.9 + 1.3
```

The website shows the value `11.200000000000001`, when I would like to show `11.2`

I have seen that the way to manage float operations is by using `toFixed(1)`, and then I get the expecte `11.2`. 
However, if I use `toFixed(1)`, for the operation `10.0 + 1.0` I get `11.0` when I would like to obtain `11`

So what I would like to have is the number with one decimal when there are decimals, and without decimals when there aren't decimals

Comment: Use the pipes, Luke https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe.  If you need something smarter, you can create your own pipe very easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is how floats are handled in Javascript. The usual way to handle this is:

1. `toFixed` when you want to pad zeros right:

```
(9.9 + 1.3).toFixed(2);
```

2. `toPrecision` when you don't need to pad right:

```
(9.9 + 1.3).toPrecision(2);
```

You would use either if defining your variable in your Angular Typescript file.

3. However, you may also want to format a number directly in the HTML template with the built-in decimal pipe:

```
{{ (9.9 + 1.3)  | number : '1.1' }}
```

The decimal pipe has quite a few options, check [the docs for more info](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe).

Answer (score 5):

To achieve expected result , use below ternary with modulo operator (%)  to get the remainder after dividing with value 1 (`11.2 % 1 = 0.2` and `11.0%1 = 0`)

```
<div>{{sum %1?sum.toFixed(1): sum}}</div>
```

sample working code for reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ozgii4?file=src/app/app.component.html

**Option2:**

Use `Math.abs` with `toFixed(1)` if you expect adding positive numbers and for negative values , you will get positive value with this approach

```
<div>{{Math.abs(sum.toFixed(1))}}</div>
```

sample working code for reference - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tsk9g?file=src/app/app.component.ts